# Using FileHelpers to read CSV by column name instead of position

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Given the following record definition

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Line
{
    public string FirstName;

    public string LastName;
}
```

And the following code to import the CSV

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Line>();
// Ignore header line
engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 1;
var records = engine.ReadFileAsList(csvFile);
```

I would like to be able to read both of these CSV files with the same result.

CSV in same order as record definition

```
FirstName,LastName
John,Doe
```

CSV with different order, with same header names however

```
LastName,FirstName
Doe,John
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the library don't support that feature

Is on the pending list for the next big release

https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/issues/122

Comment: Thanks, that's great news.